Issue sending messages to the recipient from a fresh number though WhatsApp Business API. Everything is verified
I have free messages but still not able to use the API don't know why still the messages are not received but the recipient please help me I have m job at cost they need the WhatsApp bot.


I was expecting free tier messages and that they can be send and received easily
